# Can't run start.sh for GCM Playground sample application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, sample, docker-machine

I'm very new to the google cloud messaging concept, and wanted to try out the Playground sample application but can't even get the start.sh script to run properly in the docker machine. I also nave no experience with docker, but did everything that was asked when installing and setting up the default docker machine. 
What I am trying to do exactly, is going to the parent folder of gcm-playground where the start.sh script is located (this is done from the Docker Quickstart Terminal) and executing ./start.sh.

I get the following error:

```
   ./start.sh
==> Working in web/
==> Install gulp
./start.sh: line 31: sudo: command not found
==> Install bower
./start.sh: line 38: sudo: command not found
==> Install npm dependencies
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-cssmin requires gulp-rename@'~1.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-rename,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.2.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\object-assign,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\gulp-util requires through2@'^2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\through2,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.5
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-minify-html\node_modules\gulp-util requires through2@'^2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\my-PC\Documents\gcm-playground\web\node_modules\gulp-minify-html\node_modules\through2,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.5
==> Install bower dependencies
./start.sh: line 45: bower: command not found
==> Running gulp for building
./start.sh: line 48: gulp: command not found
==> Starting Docker containers
Starting gcmplayground_server_1
Starting gcmplayground_web_1
Attaching to gcmplayground_server_1, gcmplayground_web_1
[33mweb_1    | [0mmodule.js:341
[33mweb_1    | [0m    throw err;
[33mweb_1    | [0m    ^
[33mweb_1    | [0m
[33mweb_1    | [0mError: Cannot find module 'orchestrator'
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Object.<anonymous> (/src/gcm-playground/web/node_modules/gulp/index.js:4:20)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
[33mweb_1    | [0m    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
[33mgcmplayground_web_1 exited with code 1
[0m[36mserver_1 | [0m<stream:stream from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="E4B3B4A6A882DFBA" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
[36mserver_1 | [0m<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
[36mserver_1 | [0m<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
[36mserver_1 | [0m<stream:stream from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="79E04671C097B032" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
[36mserver_1 | [0m<stream:features><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>
[36mserver_1 | [0m<iq id="70b7ced5e631b767" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>822820668927@gcm.googleapis.com/A3DF7156</jid></bind></iq>
[36mserver_1 | [0m
```

And I think it is because the sudo command, which is contained in the start.sh script is not recognized by docker. I already tried to find a way to somehow install sudo for docker, but with no luck so far.

I am obviously doing something wrong here, but please someone have this explained to me because I lack in experience..

NOTE: I am using Windows.

Comment: Because I had no luck with running the script on Windows, I tried all of the above on Linux. Here also I experienced problems with running the script. For example, I got errors for lines of the script that are empty, or the script could not navigate to folder web, etc. Because the script itself should have installed gulp, bower and npm dependencies I decided to go step by step and do this myself instead of using the script. After this I ran into the same error like above: module orchestrator was not found. These two commands saved me: rm -rf node_modules/ and npm install. FINALLY it worked.

Comment: If someone knows why I had all these troubles and could explain in a better way what was wrong, please share...

Comment: have you found the solution to your problem? can you please share?

Comment: In my first comment to this question I state  how I managed to run the sample. That however did not solve the initial problem that I had with the script and in the end I didn't really run the sample with the script, but did it by executing every command from the script step by step. This should ideally work with a script and nobody should do these steps manually. But no one gave me an answer based on my error what was wrong and how can we work with the script do to what it needs.